# Magento 2 : Show configurable Associate product name in success page

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product, order-success-page

In Order success page, I need to display the product name, but when the product is configurable I need to display the full name of the associate product not only the name of the configurable product
Help please

Comment: where you want to get configurable product child name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the below code when configurable product come on the success page. first, find where to show the product name and add the below code.

```
$configProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
$_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);
foreach ($_children as $child){
echo "Here are your child Product Name ".$child->getName()."\n";
}
```